# returning multiple values from multiple values depending on the value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that contains some values like shown down, and i want to get out some values that the summarry of theme equals to another value let's say like 13:

```
id values

1  4
2  7
3  5
4  6
```

i want to get out those values that equals 13.
a friend gave me query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tables AS t1
INNER JOIN tables AS t2
WHERE t1.id != t2.id AND t1.`values` + t2.`values` = 13
```

but it return's only two values, but let's say i want more than two values or even more like
4+7+5=16 or 4+7+5+6=22
what i mean here i dont want only two numbers, some times i need more, it depends on the value that i want. please give me a solution.

Comment: To get combinations involving more than 2 rows, you would need more joins.  Lots more...

Comment: Thanks for the edit im new here sorry, could you give me an example?

Comment: to do these permutations in SQL, you'll need as many joins as you want operands in the sum, where each has a condition like `t1.id != t2.id AND t2.id != t3.id AND t1.id != t3.id`, etc... it would get outrageous quickly.

Comment: Yes i know it's outrageous like that, but there must be other solutions with php + mysql, with php we can know the last id with this code: $next_increment= 0;
$qShowStatus= "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE data";
$qShowStatusResult= mysql_query($qShowStatus);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qShowStatusResult);
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];

Comment: but what we need i think is a loop that colects the rows one by one unil it finds the value

Comment: How many rows are in your table? What is the expected distribution of the values? What results do you want? (Is it a homework? :) I could imagine a loop in mysql, which collects combinations in a temporary table.

Comment: No it's not a homework, I can't imagine howmany rows in table, it's tomuch.

Comment: What results do you want?  A: I want the list of rows that the suumarry of them equals to my value(any value)

Comment: Are the values >= 0, or can be negative?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary table:

```
group
  sum     int
  lastid  int
  ids loooooongtext
  phase int
```

Initialize the temp table:

```
SET @SUM = 13;

INSERT INTO group
SELECT
  tables.val AS sum,
  tables.id  AS lastid,
  tables.id  AS ids
  0          AS phase
FROM tables
WHERE tables.val <= @SUM;
```

And some loop (you can use php or mysql to do the looping), half SQL, half pseudocode:

```
SET @PHASE = 0;

do
  SET @PHASE = @PHASE + 1;

  -- try to append new values to each group
  INSERT INTO group
  SELECT  ( group.sum   +   tables.val ) AS sum,
                            tables.id    AS lastid,
    CONCAT( group.ids, ",", tables.id  ) AS ids,
            @PHASE                       AS phase
  FROM       group
  INNER JOIN tables  ON group.lastid < tables.id          -- monotonity to prevent (some) duplicates
                    AND group.sum    + tables.val <= @SUM;

  -- delete dead ends
  DELETE
  FROM  group
  WHERE group.phase < @PHASE
    AND group.sum  != @SUM;

while ROW_COUNT() > 0;
```

If the loop is ready, read each row from `group`, and `group.ids` will contain the table.ids.

Comment: let's say my table name is 'music' an i have the rows 'id' and 'values', can you give me the final code to find '22'

Comment: I think you can work the junk above to php easily, just replace `tables` to music, and the sql @variables to php $variables, and it should work. Or not, I didn't test it :)

Comment: Sorry im new it's to complicate for me i cant read it easily some of them like (SET PHASE = PHASE + 1;)

Comment: That is just a helper variable which helps throwing out unusuable "results". If you are a very beginner in php/mysql, maybe you should start learning about them at (for example) http://www.tizag.com/

Comment: I'm trying to understan the code but what i don'y understand right know is (@sum) please explain it, is it a $variable or it's something else because whena i make it a variable my code outputs the error

Comment: It wanted to be an sql variable, but I haven't used them in real life. For testing, just replace it with the number you want to reach.